# undo or unshuffle the c++ shuffle functions

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone tell how to undo or unshuffle a shuffled array with the c++ shuffle function? it can be founded whith this link : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/

What I want to do is to undo my shuffled array.
I use c++ suffle function to shuffle my array and I look for a function to unshuffle this array.

Example : `array<int, 5> arr{0,1,2,3,4};`

```
shuffle(arr.begin(), arr.end(), seed);
```

**possible output:** `4,0,2,1,3`

Then I need for unshuffle function to undo arr elements positions like at the beginning.

Examlpe :

```
unshuffle(arr.begin(), arr.end(), seed);
```

**output:** `0,1,2,3,4`

Thank you

Comment: It's not something you can reverse...

Comment: If you need both shuffled and unshuffled, you should probably copy the array nad kepp ony copy unchanged.

Comment: Alternatively, if you cannot make a copy and the array is initially sorted (such as in your example), then you can "unshuffle" it by sorting: `std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end())`.

Comment: Maybe if you designed a custom random number generator, that can be reversed. Then you could shuffle again with a reversed randomness. I'm just hypothesising; I don't know if thar would work.

Answer (score 3):

How about this design (using a fictive class `Array` that might be `std::array`):

You have a class `ReversableShuffledArray`. This class has two members, `Array<Datatype> data` and `Array<size_t> shuffle_order`, and methods `void shuffle` and `Datatype& operator[]`.

It is initialized by feeding it with the data in some way (especially a move constructor), and it puts the data in the member `data`. At this moment, it creates the content of `shuffle_order`, which contains `{0,1,2,3....}` and has the same size as `data`.

When `shuffle` is called, *not* `data` but `shuffle_order` is shuffled.

`operator[](size_t index)` is defined by `return data[shuffle_order[index]];`. Simple as that. `data` itself is never shuffled.

(Should be obvious how to do the non-shuffled access, so I won't execute that.)

Of course, this can also be done procedurally, without the class.

Alternatively, you can again shuffle a counting like `shuffle_order`, use it to apply it on the array in question and then create another array `reverse_shuffle_order` from it which you can use the reverse the process.

(This does not help you if you have no control about the shuffling, though, but in the question, your wrote "I use c++ suffle function to shuffle my array", so I assume you do.)

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life

Comment: @Enock Glad I could be of help. Accepting the answer would be nice then ;) (click on the check mark below it's rating)